Probability of choosing the heaviest box of candy?
This is a simple question that has been bugging me for a while.
Suppose there are 100 boxes of candy and each box has a weight (let's assume no ties). We randomly take a sample of 15 boxes (without replacement).

Q1: What is the probability that this sample of 15 will contain the heaviest box from the full population (i.e. from the 100 boxes)?
Q2: What is the probability that the largest box in this sample of 15 will contain a box in the top 3 heaviest boxes from the full population (i.e. from the 100 boxes)?

I tried to analyze this problem in 2 scenarios.

Scenario 1: We do not know the probability distribution of the full population
Q1: The probability that the heaviest box among the 15 is the heaviest from the original 100 is equal to the probability that we selected the heaviest box in our sample of 15.
$$ P(\text{heaviest in 15 is heaviest in 100}) = \frac{15}{100} = 0.15 = 15\% $$
This is because each box has an equal chance of being selected, and we need the heaviest box to be one of the 15 we picked.
Q2:  We need to calculate the probability that the heaviest box in our sample of 15 is among the top 3% (which is 3 boxes) of the 100 boxes. Using basic logic:
The probability of not selecting any of the top 3 boxes in a single draw is:
$$ P(\text{not selecting top 3 in one draw}) = \frac{97}{100} $$
For all 15 draws to not include any of the top 3, this needs to happen 15 times in a row:
$$ P(\text{not selecting top 3 in 15 draws}) = \left(\frac{97}{100}\right)^{15} $$
Therefore, the probability of selecting at least one of the top 3 boxes in 15 draws is:
$$ P(\text{selecting at least one top 3 in 15 draws}) = 1 - \left(\frac{97}{100}\right)^{15} $$
$$ = 1 - 0.6301 = 0.3699 $$
So, the probability that the heaviest box in the 15 selected is in the top 3% of all boxes is approximately 36.99%.
I verified this with a computer simulation:


Scenario 2: We know the probability distribution of the full population
Suppose we are given the probability density function $f(x)$ and the cumulative distribution function $F(x)$ of the weight distribution.
Let  $X_1, X_2, ..., X_{15}$ be the weights of the 15 selected boxes and
let $Y = \max(X_1, X_2, ..., X_{15}) $
Define the cumulative distribution function of $Y$, where $Y$ is the maximum of 15 independent, identically distributed random variables $X₁, X₂, ..., X₁₅$:
$$ F_Y(y) = P(Y \leq y) = P(X_1 \leq y \text{ and } X_2 \leq y \text{ and } ... \text{ and } X_{15} \leq y) $$
Since the $X_i$ are independent and identically distributed, this probability is the product of the individual probabilities:
$$ F_Y(y) = P(X_1 \leq y) \cdot P(X_2 \leq y) \cdot ... \cdot P(X_{15} \leq y) $$
Each $P(X_i ≤ y)$ is just the CDF of $X_i$, which we denote as $F(y)$:
$$ F_Y(y) = F(y) \cdot F(y) \cdot ... \cdot F(y) = [F(y)]^{15} $$
Now, to get the probability density function of $Y$, we need to differentiate $F_Y(y)$ with respect to $y$:
$$ f_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy}[F_Y(y)] = \frac{d}{dy}[F(y)^{15}] $$
This is where we apply the chain rule. The derivative of $x^n$ is $n x^{(n-1)}$ multiplied by the derivative of $x$. In our case, $x$ is $F(y)$ and n is 15:
$$ f_Y(y) = 15 \cdot [F(y)]^{14} \cdot \frac{d}{dy}[F(y)] $$
The derivative of $F(y)$ is just the PDF of $X$, which we denote as $f(y)$:
$$ f_Y(y) = 15 \cdot [F(y)]^{14} \cdot f(y) $$
Q1: I am not sure what I need to do to make sure that this to be the heaviest of all 100. My guess is that I might need to integrate this distribution?
$$ P(\text{heaviest in 15 is heaviest in 100}) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 15 \cdot F(x)^{14} \cdot f(x) \, dx $$
Q2: For the probability that the heaviest in the 15 boxes is in the top 3% of all heaviest boxes:
First, we find the 97th percentile weight:
$$ w_{97} = F^{-1}(0.97) $$
Then, the probability is:
$$ P(\text{heaviest in 15 is in top 3%}) = 1 - F(w_{97})^{15} $$

Are my answers correct?
PS 1 : (some closing notes)

Had we dealt with the mean instead of the max, I think this question would have been much easier (i.e. use Central Limit Theorem and Law of Large Numbers)
I am guessing that if we choose a Uniform Probability distribution for Scenario 2, then Scenario 1 and Scenario 2 will have the same answers for both questions?
I wonder if in general, if we knew the probability distribution in Scenario 2, we could then compare our odds of succeeding in both situations



Q2 answer is wrong. If instead of $15$, your sample had $100$, you’d be saying that a sample of 100 or of 100 has a probability of $1-(97/100)^100$ of having something in the top 3, which is clearly wrong. The sample is taken without replacement.

thank you Eric ... is there a way to fix Q2?

Q2: You should have $1-\frac{97}{100}\times\frac{96}{99}\cdots\frac{83}{86}$, or $1-\frac{85\times84\times83}{100\times99\times98}=1-\frac{1411}{2310}=\frac{899}{2310}\approx 0.3891775$

@ Daniel: Is this for Scenario 1 or Scenario 2? (or is it the same for both)?

It is the same for both scenarios, because the distribution is irrelevant.

@ Daniel: thank you .... I believe you, but I am struggling to understand why the probability distribution is irrelevant . Could you please help me understand why?

Whether you know the distribution or not is irrelevant, as long as there is no ambiguity, i.e. no ties for heaviest in Q1, and in Q2 there are three boxes that are each heavier than the other $97$. This is the case with probability $1$ as long as the distribution is continuous.  Then your Scenario 1 answers are correct.
Your calculations in Scenario 2 are for questions that were not asked.  $f_Y(y)$ is the probability density for the weight of the heaviest box in the $15$ selected, but this doesn't tell you whether that is the heaviest box of the $100$.

Thank you Robert Israel ... can you please explain what you mean by : "Your calculations in Scenario 2 are for questions that were not asked."?

I am having difficulty understanding this point "Whether you know the distribution or not is irrelevant" .  I would have thought for some strange distribution, e.g. extremely right skewed - knowing the distribution would result in different answers compared to not knowing the distribution?

@user430997 For Q1, you are just looking for one box which is distinguishable from the others.  If you were looking for the only red box then the answer would be the same.  Q2 is similar but there are three red boxes.

Your Q1 answer is right, and your Q2 answer is wrong, as indicated by the comment of
Daniel Mathias.
For Q2, it is easiest to compute the complement.  Let $~A~$ denote the probability that the heaviest of the $~15~$ boxes is not among the top $~3~$ heaviest.
Then, the desired computation will be
$$1 - A.$$

The heaviest of the $~15~$ boxes will not be among the top $~3~$ heaviest, if and only if all of the $~15~$ boxes are not among the top $~3~$ heaviest.
The probability of this happening is
$$A = \frac{\binom{97}{15}}{\binom{100}{15}}.$$
An alternative way of computing this is that the probability may be computed as
$$A = \frac{97}{100} \times \frac{96}{99} \times \cdots \times \frac{83}{86}. \tag1 $$
In (1) above, the $~\displaystyle \frac{97}{100}~$ factor represents the probability that the first (of 15) is not among the top 3 heaviest.
Then, in (1) above, assuming that the first of 15 is not among the top 3 heaviest, there are 99 balls to choose from, of which 96 are not among the top 3 heaviest.
This thinking carries over to all 15 choices.
So, the final computation is
$$1 - A = 1 - \frac{\binom{97}{15}}{\binom{100}{15}}.$$

thank you so much! Is this for both scenario 1 and scenario 2?

@user430997 Unless I am mistaken, this applies to both scenario 1 and scenario 2.  That is, I don't see how it is relevant whether you have any knowledge of the weights of the $~100~$ balls, since you are selecting $~15~$ balls at random.  Another way of thinking about it is to imagine that the balls are labeled Ball-1, Ball-2, ..., Ball-100, you choose $~15~$ balls at random, and you want to know if any of the $~15~$ balls are part of Ball-1, Ball-2, or Ball-3.

WOW! beautiful explanation! I now finally understand this .... thank you so much!
